# For-comprehension for io monad prints nothing

Tags: scala, io, scalaz

I'm experimenting with IO monad and this is what I wrote:

```
val io: IO[String] = "asdfasdf".pure[IO]

val i: IO[Unit] = for{
  str <- io
} yield {
  println(str).pure[IO]
}

i.unsafePerformIO() // Performing io ops
```

The code produces no output. The following code in turn works as expected:

```
val io: IO[Unit] = "asdfasdf".pure[IO].flatMap(println(_).pure[IO])
io.unsafePerformIO() //prints asdfasdf
```

Why? What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just hit a huge annoyance with scala: inferred `Unit`

```
for{
  str <- io
} yield {
  println(str).pure[IO]
}
```

This expression is an `IO[IO[Unit]]` but because you told scala (via the value's type) that you wanted an `IO[Unit]`, it has basically transformed the expression as follows:

```
for{
  str <- io
} yield {
  println(str).pure[IO] // <-- this IO action is basically thrown away
  ()                    // <-- inserted a Unit return
}
```

**Aside...** note that this transformation appears to be possible because `IO[A]` is invariant in `A`. The same thing would happen if you substitute `IList` for `IO` *but not `List`* (which is covariant in its type parameter), in which case the snippet will not compile

**Back to the answer...**

Instead, you should have written:

```
for {
  str <- io
  _   <- println(str).pure[IO]
}
yield ()
```

**More Asides...**

Personally I only use `expr.pure[IO]` where `expr` is a pure expression, and I use `IO(expr)` where `expr` is side-effecting, so I prefer:

```
for {
  str <- io
  _   <- IO(println(str))
}
yield ()
```

And finally, note that this is equivalent to:

```
io >>= IO.putStrLn
```